# Calculate the derivative of $f(x) = \| x\|^2.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a normed space $E$ with the induced inner product and a map $f:E\to R$ such that $f(x) = \|x\|^2.$ I want to compute the derivative of this map.

We have that 
$$f(x+h)=\|x\|^2+\|h\|^2+2\langle x,h\rangle=f(x)+o(\|h\|)+df_{x}(h).$$

Clearly the derivative $df_x(h) = 2\langle x,h\rangle$ is linear in $h.$ We also want to show that $df_x(h)$ is continuous in $h$. This can be done by simply observing that $$|df_x(h)|\leq 2\|x\|\cdot \|h\|$$ and therefore 
$$\|df_x\|\leq 2\|x\|$$ implying that $df_x$ is continuous in $h.$

I also want to show that the derivative $df_x$ is $C^{1}.$ For this we have to show that the map $x\to df_x$ is continuous. Therefore observe that for each $h\in E$ we have that,
$$|df_x(h)-df_y(h)|=2|\langle x-y,h\rangle|\leq \|x-y\|\cdot2\|h\|.$$
I am not sure how to proceed after this step. Any hints will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is a inner product induced by a norm? Most norms don't come from inner products.

Comment: Oh I think I meant the other way around.

Comment: If you fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta = \varepsilon/2\lvert h \rvert$ you are done: $2\lVert h \rVert \cdot \lVert x-y \rVert < \varepsilon$. But it seems you got the idea in the other steps. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use that the inner product is [bilinear and continuous, so $C^1$](https://www.gold-saucer.org/math/taylor/taylor.pdf). Now, write $f$ as a composition:
$$x\longmapsto(x,x)\longmapsto\langle x,x\rangle = f(x)$$
and apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the norm $\|f\|=\sup \|f(x)\|$ where the supremum runs over all $\|x\| = 1.$ (If such set of $x$ is empty, you are dealing with a trivial case; the details are left to you.) So, set $\|h\| = 1$ and get that the linear transformation $d_xf-d_yf$ has norm $\leq 2\|x - y|.$ So, when $y \to x,$ $d_yf \to d_xf.$ Q.E.D.